# Easily disabling and enabling a monitor in a multimonitor setup

Tags: windows-10, command-line, multiple-monitors

I have 2 external monitors, and 2 laptops, one work one personal.

I switch the primary monitor between my work laptop(usb-c) and personal laptop(hdmi) through the monitor menu.

When I'm on my work laptop, I want to use my personal laptop as well, the problem with this is that my personal laptop still thinks the primary monitor is connected, and therefore gives it screenspace and opens apps on it (which I can't see, as it's using the work laptop signal).

It's possible to go into the nvidia driver menu or even the windows display settings, do disable that monitor and only use the other external display.

But I'd like this to be done with much more ease, i.e. potentially double clicking on a batch script that's on the desktop, which would turn on and off my primary monitor in the personal laptop.

Or perhaps if it was possible to detect  that the monitor is taking different input, without clicking anything, that would be even better, but probably not possible.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can press Windows+P to open the Project Panel on the bottom left side of the Display.

There you can choose „PC Screen only“, this will effectively disable output to your secondary Display.

When you want to use your secondary Display again, just repeat and this Time choose „Extend“.

This will re-enable the secondary Display.

Comment: After pressing `Win`+`P` to open the panel, you can keep holding `Win` and press `P` repeatedly again to change the selection. `Esc` closes the panel.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a bad solution in theory. However, my second monitor is a bit weird. I usually need to disconnect and reconnect it to my laptop on startup for it to start getting signal. When I use win+p to switch, the secondary monitor stops working again, and I need to reconnect it. I almost need something like this but to switch, between 3 monitor setup and 2 monitor setup.